# How to check if the MongoDB value is Null (or not) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Given the following document in a valid MongoDB query, how can I check the value of `name` to see if it's `Null` ?

```
{
    "_id" : {
            "userId" : "2a4c18a7-e12c-4f58-a08c-17f52a01d3a0"
    },
    "name" : null
}
```

I've omitted other fields (not relevant to this question). Notice how the `name` field has a `null` value? This is legit .. meaning ... I can't change my mongo query to filter out these. Some of the documents returned back will have a `null` value.

Here is what the field looks like, in Studio3T:

[image: Schema in Studio3T]

So is there a way to check this value, in JavaScript?

I tried the following, which failed to work:

```
let usersCursor = usersCollection.find(<some query>);

usersCursor.forEach(user => {

    if (user.name === null)
    {
        // Then do something. This code is never called.
    };

});
```

Comment: Can you share your code including the query? For now we don't know where the var `name` is coming from. Also it seems you are querying multiple documents so you are trying to filter out docs with null name right?

Comment: @Dharmaraj thanks for the comment. Nope, i'm not trying to filter out any docs with `null` name. I know how to do this with my `.find(..)` query. I do -not- want to change my query. I'm trying to interrogate the field-value in mongodb shell -after- i've retrieved the results from MongoDb (in my JavaScript code).

Comment: Yes, I meant you want to trigger some function for every document that has null in name field? Can you update your question with the query and the function that code snippet is part of?

Comment: Okay - updated the OP.

Comment: The `find` returns a promise. You need to `await` it or use Promise chaining. Do you have either in original code and missed it in this post by chance?

Comment: i do not have it. Nor have i seen `await` in any mongodb shell scripts.

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @Dharmaraj, you don't need any `await` in the mongo shell, the mongo shell is not Node.js - well actually it is but you don't use the node.js driver.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes, OP never mentioned that they are using shell in the question and it's tagged with Javascript so I assumed NodeJS driver is being used here before the code snippet was added in the question.

Comment: Did you try `usersCollection.find(<some query>).forEach(...)`? See [Iterate a Cursor in mongosh](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#iterate-a-cursor-in-mongosh)

Comment: Your screenshot is not really helpful! Is `name` a sub-document of `emailverification`?

Comment: `name` is a field in the document. On the root level of the document. Also, in the OP .. you can see that i'm doing `find().forEach()` already ... that works fine. It's when i'm iterating through the cursor, I'm trying to see if the `name` field has a `null` value, as shown in screen shot, above.